# PHP: Echoing an input submitted from a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form which contains one text field. Now, I'm trying to echo out the contents of that input after the form was submitted. Here's my code for the same:

```
<script>    
    function postResultss()
    {
        document.write("<?php echo ($_POST['tweet1']); ?>");
    }
</script>

<form method = "POST">
    <input type = "text" name = "tweet1">
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" onclick = "postResultss()" />
</form>
```

The above code is inside a PHP file. However, nothing gets echoed out on submitting the form. The function does get called as expected, because I have tried echoing custom messages while debugging. However, nothing gets echoed out when I try to echo the value of `$_POST['tweet1']`, where `tweet1` is the name of the input text field whose contents I'm trying to display.

What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: PHP inside JS. mmmmm, no.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari And why not?

Comment: Firstly, because the button is a submit button the attached javascript function `postResultss()` is unlikely to get called - unless it has `event.preventDefault()` in the js function. Secondly, the POSTed var will NOT be available to the js function at the point of clicking the button - only AFTER the form has been submitted and event then this is the wrong approach to show theposted values.

Comment: @RamRaider Well, when I try to echo something like `echo ("felicity");` inside my JS function, the message does get displayed. Which means that the JS function is indeed being called on submitting the form.

Comment: OK, so the js function gets called but the POSTed variables will not be available at the time of clicking the button

Comment: @RamRaider  Any idea why the POSTed variables aren't available when the program enters the JS function?

Comment: They become available once the form has been submitted afaik, not during the process

Answer (score 2):

You do a submit and onclick. That goes wrong. Further, don't do a document.write!

Do this as better alternative (no php in js):

```
<?php
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') // check if post
      echo htmlentities($_POST['tweet1']);
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="tweet1">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Tweet!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use javascript to write the content which, in your example wouldn't work, use php to generate the response for the user to see

```
<form method = "POST">
    <input type = "text" name = "tweet1">
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value='Submit' />
    <div id='msgs'>
    <?php
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['tweet1'] ) ){
           echo $_POST['tweet1'];
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the javascript function is called before the form submits (so before php can print out the echo), and since the page updates the document.write is being overwritten from the new request.

Why dont you try something like this?

```
<form method = "POST">
    <?php echo ($_POST['tweet1']); ?>
    <input type = "text" name = "tweet1">
    <br>
    <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

or:

```
<script>
var text = "<?php echo ($_POST['tweet1']); ?>";
if(text != ""){
   alert(text);
}
</script>
<form method = "POST">

    <input type = "text" name = "tweet1">
    <br>
    <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: or a document write instead of the alert

Comment: This would work, but I need to call out a function on submitting the form, so this solution may not be helpful in my case.

Comment: wait so do you want the text to be display after or before submitting the form?

Comment: After submitting the form. That's why I was trying to trigger the `onclick` event in my submit field.